# How to do searching from 10 million records

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch, search

There is an object and it has approximately 10 million record and i want to apply searching in VF page can any one tell me how to do that without reaching the governor limits. Any idea or some code will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Can you specify whether you would like your user to search in those 10 million records, or you want to query 10 million records?
What would be the search criteria?

Comment: i want my user to search a list of records from those 10 million records

Answer (score 3):

There is specific developer documentation for dealing with scenarios like this in [Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_introduction.htm). In particular, have a read of [Large Data Volumes Case Studies - Custom Search Functionality](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_case_studies_custom_search_functionality.htm)

Generally speaking, you will want to search over indexed fields of a single object and avoid wild cards.

Reading up on how to make SOQL queries selective will also be helpful - [Working with Very Large SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm) and [Developing Selective Force.com Queries through the Query Resource Feedback Parameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Selective_Force.com_Queries_through_the_Query_Resource_Feedback_Parameter_Pilot)

Comment: I think you have a typo. Has a read of? Also in re: wildcards, don't you only need to avoid leading wildcards?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I was basing that off the [Custom Search Functionality](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_case_studies_custom_search_functionality.htm) which had "For example, very specific values (i.e., no wild cards) used SOQL to query, which allowed indexes to enhance performance.".

Comment: @AdrianLarson  Certainly the second link I just added for selective queries only mentions leading '%' wildcards as problematic.

Comment: Gotcha. I think leading wildcards are just *especially* degrading to performance, but when you're dealing with 1M+ records, probably better to avoid them entirely.